# Hide tab on subform

Tags: ms-access, vba7

I have a form with a tab control. I have a cmd button with the following code:

```
Page16.Visible = False
```

This works. I have several cmd buttons as a work around for multi row bug in tabs.

On this form I have a subform with another tab control.  I set up the a cmd button on the subform to hide those tabs. I used the same code as above swapping out the cmdpg and page number.  The names are correct.

I tried renaming the tabs and I tried using the pageindex as below:

```
TabListCollection.Pages(1).Visible = False
```

I get the following.

> The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error:
>
> - The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
> - There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

Answer (score 0):

The subform knows "itself", so try:

```
Me.Pages(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: That did not work either (same error message), although I did try this before.  I feel something is corrupted/off.  I created a new form and used the Page16.visible = False as above and it all worked perfectly.  I'm not clear on what happened.